# How to flip the mirror modifier? So I may edit the mirrored side

Tags: modifiers, mirror

So using the mirror modifier, I understand I manipulate the components of my object in edit mode. This gets reflected to the mirrored object.

What I want to know is if there is an option to use the mirrored side to edit if I need to, say in another view for example I may only have a background ref image that suits that side.

[image: mirror]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the mirror modifier allow editing of both sides in edit mode by clicking the triangle icon in the modifier:

[image]

However, moving the mirrored side may be confusing, as it will always behave as if you are editing the corresponding selection on the non-mirrored side.

## Flipping the model manually

There a few was to do this, but the fastest way I know of is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> (or Y or Z, depending on your mirror axis) in object mode, making sure the pivot point is at the same spot as the mirror point.